# Android Event Handling

Tags: android, android-event

Which type of model is used by android to handle events. Is it **delegation model** or **event model**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android system uses the event model. The delegate/ion model is used in code for iOS only.

Comment: Ok, if it uses event model then why do we use onClickListeners for buttons which doesn't return either true or false for the event to be dispatched to the parent (say a view on which button is added)?

Answer (score 0):

Android uses Event based dispatching.For more, please refer [this](http://www.therealjoshua.com/2012/03/event-dispatching-sending-messages/)

Answer (score 0):

Android uses the Event Model to handle the events.